# Android Ruboto IRB - How to start demo irb server

Tags: android, ruboto

I just installed [Ruboto-irb](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ruboto.irb) on my Android device to run the Ruby IRB on it.

The documentation at https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/wiki/Using-Ruboto-IRB-to-jump-start-development says that one of the best ways to push scripts is to use the demo-irb-server and access it remotely.

How do I start the [demo-irb-server](https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto-irb/blob/master/assets/demo-scripts/demo-irb-server.rb) on the Android device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had no idea what to do so I started typing random stuff on the Ruboto IRB command line on the device. Eventually, the following command worked:

```
require 'demo-irb-server'
```

My device was connected to my wireless LAN and its IP was 192.168.0.108.

I then hit http://192.168.0.108:8005 from my desktop computer, and it was able to access the demo IRB server on the Android. I then proceeded to play with scripts, write my own and have fun.